# Elasticsearch - Designing a proper structure

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm trying to pass data from MySQL to elastica to run the search engine using elastica. I started by creating maps based on structures mysql. I would like to advise you that I made a good thinking and organization of this map, and if something is missing in these maps according to you, maybe something is not needed.

Tabels:

1. Documents
2. Table view documents

So the structure of mysql looks like this:

1. http://pastebin.com/e6haBmMx
2. http://pastebin.com/AJLDAAdM

And now my preliminary maps elastica:

1. http://pastebin.com/mcg33LQw
2. http://pastebin.com/ytQDTE3B

And now briefly what it is to have the job search. It presents in points:

1. Each field is to be searched by name
2. Each field is to be filtered after id
3. Each field is to be filtered by name

I look forward to every suggestion.

Comment: is the query going to be similar to `select * from index_name where field_name = xyz`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I was trying to ask exactly what type of queries are you going to run? Are they going to be on any field and what would it return? From what I understand your query is going to be on any field and you would want all objects which match those fields. If that is the case will your query have partial text search?